# "invalid file" error message when uploading videos in ckfinder

Tags: php, video, ckfinder

I want to allow users to upload videos (`mp4` , `webm` and `ogv` formats) via **ckfinder** to a directory named `video`. I added following options to **ckFinder/config.php** file:

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Video',
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'video',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'video',
        'maxSize' => "64M",
        'allowedExtensions' => 'mp4,webm,ogv',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

When I'm trying to upload a video in allowed format a simple **invalid file** error message is shown with no other details.

I'm sure that format and size of the uploaded files is valid.

How can I find where is the problem?

**Update :**
According to @zaak comment, I just had to increase `post_max_size` option in php.ini.

Comment: Please make sure the size of the uploaded file doesn't exceed limits for PHP uploads defined in `php.ini`: `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`.
Is there any input in server error log?

Comment: Thanks @zaak, `post_max_size` was low.